# Copying folders with cygwin

Tags: cygwin, file-transfer, file-attributes

The folder produced by

```
cp -r myfolder myfolder2
```

is marked `shared` as reported by "It is shared with other people. Are you sure that you want to delete it?" dialog in windows when I try to delete the folder. When I use the same cp command in another machine, I run into permission issues instead. Sometimes, I cannot navigate into the folder by Explorer. It pops up "No permissions. Do you want to take them?" dialong and once I press "Yes", the permissions are granted. In the other cases, I cannot delete the copied folders using Explorer. I have to modify the permissions manually in this case (I can add all permissions to my user when there are none originally) or use cygwin's `rm command` with `-f flag`.

You can reproduce the issue using

```
mkdir f1 && mkdir f1\f2 && echo 1 >> f1\f2\file && cp -r f1 f2
```

I need one folder deeper path to create deletion problems on the second machine

```
mkdir f1 && mkdir f1\f2 && mkdir f1\f2\f3 && echo 1 >> f1\f2\f3\file && cp -r f1 f2
```

Now, try to delete f2. It won't because `Authenticated Users` permissions do not propagate down to f2\f2\f3.

What should I ask from the author of the program?

Comment: Does this also happen, if you copy it with `cp -rp .....`?

Answer (score 0):

Windows command

```
icacls f2 /T /reset
```

makes f2 permissions iherited from the parent folder. This satisifes my goal. However, the answer does not answer what the hell happens with file attributes.